# The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST in laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8, delete-method

I get the following error with the code below.

> The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:
> GET, HEAD, POST

**Controller**

```
public function destroy(Post $post)
{
    $post->delete();

    return back();
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::delete('/posts/{post}', [PostController::class, 'destroy']);
```

**View**

```
<form action="{{ route('posts', $post) }}" method="POST" >
    @csrf
    @method('delete')
    <button type="submit" class="text-blue-500">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Instead of `action="{{ route('posts', $post) }}"` try `action="/posts/{{ $post }}"`

Comment: I tried it and I was directed to a 404 Not Found page.

Comment: Fixed it by changing my route to `Route::delete('/posts/{post}', [PostController::class, 'destroy'])->name('posts.destroy');`

Answer (score 0):

**Route:**

Route::delete('/admin/user_list/{id}', [UserController::class, 'destroy'])->name('admin.user_list');

**Controller:**

```
public function destroy(Request $request, $id)
{
  User::where('id', $id)->delete();
  return redirect()->back()->withSuccess('Your record deleted successfuly');

}
```

**View:**

```
form action="{{ route('admin.user_list', $rows->id) }}" method="post"
```

```
@method('DELETE')
@csrf

<button onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');" type="submit" value="delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
    <span>DELETE</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

just follow the sequence for this:

```
@method('DELETE')
@csrf
```

and it works for me